# Difference between "id" and "_id" fields in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, mongoid

Is there any difference between using the field ID or _ID from a MongoDB document?

I am asking this, because I usually use "_id", however I saw this sort({id:-1}) in the documentation: http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Optimizing+Object+IDs#OptimizingObjectIDs-Sortbyidtosortbyinsertiontime

**EDIT**

Turns out the docs were wrong.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

I expect it's just a typo in the documentation. The `_id` field is primary key for every document. It's called `_id` and is also accessible via `id`. Attempting to use an `id` key may result in a `illegal ObjectId format` error.

That section is just indicating that the automatically generated ObjectIDs start with a timestamp so it's possible to sort your documents automatically. This is pretty cool since the `_id` is automatically indexed in every collection. See http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/Object+IDs for more information. Specifically under "BSON ObjectID Specification".

> A BSON ObjectID is a 12-byte value consisting of a 4-byte timestamp (seconds since epoch), a 3-byte machine id, a 2-byte process id, and a 3-byte counter. Note that the timestamp and counter fields must be stored big endian unlike the rest of BSON.

Comment: is the `_id` mandatory for each document of a collection? in other words, can I create a new document without the `_id` field?

Comment: @KevinMeredith As specified [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/bson-types/#objectid), yes, an `_id` field is mandatory. «In MongoDB, each document stored in a collection requires a unique `_id` field that acts as a primary key. If an inserted document omits the `_id` field, the MongoDB driver automatically generates an `ObjectId` for the `_id` field».

Answer (score 16):

The `_id` field is the default field for Bson ObjectId's and it is,by default, indexed.

`_id` and id are not the same.  You may also choose to add a field called `id` if you want, but it will not be index unless you add an index.

It is just a typo in the docs.

Answer (score 8):

id is an alias for _id in mongoid.id would return the _id of the document.
https://github.com/mongodb/mongoid/blob/master/lib/mongoid/fields.rb#L47

if the _id field is not specified an ObjectedId is generated automatically.

Answer (score 5):

My two cents:

## The _id field

`MongoDB` assigns an `_id` field to each document and assigns primary index on it. There're ways by which we can apply secondary indices as well. By default, `MongoDB` creates values for the `_id` field of type `ObjectID`. This value is defined in `BSON` spec and it's structured this way:

> ObjectID (12 bytes HEX string) = Date (4 bytes, a timestamp value representing number of seconds since the Unix epoch) + MAC address (3 bytes) + PID (2 bytes) + Counter (3 bytes)