# Pymongo UUID search not returning documents that definitely exist

Tags: python, pymongo, uuid

Trying to define a function in python that can search for a given UUID like so:

```
def getid(in_id):
    return list(CollectionVar.find({"_id":UUID(in_id)}))
```

And passing in a UUID. **I can take a UUID I know exists from Studio 3T** like so:

```
db.getCollection("CollectionName").find({"_id":UUID("5002aa11-eeb7-4e68-a121-dd51497d2572")})
```

And the above query returns precisely **one document**. That same UUID in the python query returns absolutely nothing. I can find documents on other (non UUID) fields easily enough, for example the following works fine on that same document from earlier:

```
def getname(fn,sn):
    return list(CollectionVar.find({"Firstname":re.compile(fn, re.IGNORECASE), "Surname":re.compile(sn, re.IGNORECASE)}))
```

This seems like a problem with the uuid.UUID class rather than a pymongo issue? Can anyone see the problem?

PyMongo Version 3.6.1

Answer (score 7):

The issue is that PyMongo uses a legacy method of encoding/decoding UUID values by default. You probably want to configure the PyMongo client to use the more modern, cross-language compatible "standard" UUID representation:

```
client = MongoClient(MONGODB_URI, uuidRepresentation="standard")
```

Now you should be able to query directly using Python `uuid.UUID` instances:

```
from uuid import UUID

items = client["item_database"]["items"].find_one({
    "uuid": UUID("187382af-1369-43e6-a0ba-d345886c986c")
})
```

Answer (score 5):

I've solved this. For anyone else who hits this issue the solution is below:

```
from bson.binary import Binary, UUID_SUBTYPE

def getcust(inid):
    newuuid=uuid.UUID(inid).bytes
    return list(DealershipConsumer.find({"_id": Binary(bytes(bytearray(newuuid)), UUID_SUBTYPE)}))
```

UUID_SUBTYPE needs to be set to whatever subtype of UUID you use - in my case it's 4.

Comment: Note that you can (and should) extract the UUID version from the UUID bytes rather than assuming a fixed value.

Comment: `bytes(bytearray(` doesn't seem useful

Answer (score 3):

You could specify the UUID type you're using when getting the db :

```
import bson
import pymongo

mongo_client = pymongo.MongoClient(mongo_uri, document_class=dict)
db = mongo_client.get_database(                              
    "my_db_name",                                                          
    bson.codec_options.CodecOptions(uuid_representation=bson.binary.UUID_SUBTYPE),
)
```

If you want to read more about Mongo best practices while using UUIDs, [this article](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/987203/Best-Practices-for-GUID-data-in-MongoDB) might help.

Also, here are [the docs](https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/codec_options.html) about `codec_options`

Answer (score 0):

I've scraped this from `pymongo-2.8.1` in the `bson.binary.UUIDLegacy` class's docstring/comment, might be usefull

```
  >>> import uuid
  >>> from bson.binary import Binary, UUIDLegacy, UUID_SUBTYPE
  >>> my_uuid = uuid.uuid4()
  >>> coll = db.test
  >>> coll.uuid_subtype = UUID_SUBTYPE
  >>> coll.insert({'uuid': Binary(my_uuid.bytes, 3)})
  ObjectId('...')
  >>> coll.find({'uuid': my_uuid}).count()
  0
  >>> coll.find({'uuid': UUIDLegacy(my_uuid)}).count()
  1
  >>> coll.find({'uuid': UUIDLegacy(my_uuid)})[0]['uuid']
  UUID('...')
  >>>
  >>> # Convert from subtype 3 to subtype 4
  >>> doc = coll.find_one({'uuid': UUIDLegacy(my_uuid)})
  >>> coll.save(doc)
  ObjectId('...')
  >>> coll.find({'uuid': UUIDLegacy(my_uuid)}).count()
  0
  >>> coll.find({'uuid': {'$in': [UUIDLegacy(my_uuid), my_uuid]}}).count()
  1
  >>> coll.find_one({'uuid': my_uuid})['uuid']
  UUID('...')
```

Answer (score -2):

You need to use `ObjectId` instead of `UUID`.
Try this, it works for me:

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId


def getid(in_id):
    return list(CollectionVar.find({"_id":ObjectId(in_id)}))
```

Comment: "InvalidId: '5002aa11-eeb7-4e68-a121-dd51497d2572' is not a valid ObjectId, it must be a 12-byte input or a 24-character hex string" is the error message when using bson.objectid's ObjectId class. Do I have the wrong one?

Comment: @MichaelBrown are you sure that your "_id" is UUID? If I don't mistake it's generating automatically by mongo and looks like "507f191e810c19729de860ea".

Comment: Can you look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694460/difference-between-id-and-id-fields-in-mongodb?

Comment: from Studio 3T (where searching for UUID("5002aa11-eeb7-4e68-a121-dd51497d2572") works fine) - https://i.imgur.com/H1ixJxe.png