# How to update mongodb collection if there is no primary key

Tags: mongodb

I have one collection and in that collection there is no primary key id but there is _id. how can i add one more field to the collection as primary key id

Comment: Can you clarify your question by updating it to show a specific example of what you're looking for?

Comment: Hi, the field _id into documents is de primary key per defect in MongoDB. If you need to update one or more documents you can use db.collection.update https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/#db.collection.update Only requires that you define a query to filter and define the json with new values.

Answer (score 1):

`_id` is the primary in mongodb. See also [Difference between “id” and “_id” fields in MongoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694460/difference-between-id-and-id-fields-in-mongodb)