# Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the immutable field '_id'

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to UPDATE fields in mongo database. However, I get the hollowing error.

> MongoError: Performing an update on the path '_id' would modify the
>   immutable field '_id'

My Code to update.

```
app.put("/api/inventory/:sku", (req, res, next) => {
  const inventory = new Inventory({
    _id: req.body.id,
    sku: req.body.sku,
    total_qty: req.body.total_qty,
    current_qty: req.body.current_qty
  });
  Inventory.updateOne({ sku: req.params.sku }, req.body).then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Update successful!" });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`_id` is auto-generated - for a more in-depth explanation about what it is, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9694625/10221765).

You can't create this field - it's created when you create any new document. You need to use the `id` field (no leading underscore `_`):

```
const inventory = new Inventory({
  id: req.body.id,
  sku: req.body.sku,
  total_qty: req.body.total_qty,
  current_qty: req.body.current_qty
});
```

Comment: In this mongoDB tutorial: https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/paging-with-the-bucket-pattern--part-2. an updateOne query affects the key "_id", so my question is why is that example working and this one not working, is it a driver issue.

Comment: You can create the `_id` field, but you can't alter it after it's created. @MargachChris in the tutorial they use `$setOnInsert`, which actually does not update the `_id` field but creates it if the document doesn't exists.

Answer (score 10):

It seems you only need to update one `Inventory` record. You can simply do this:

```
app.put("/api/inventory/:sku", (req, res, next) => {
  return Inventory.updateOne(
    { sku: req.params.sku },  // <-- find stage
    { $set: {                // <-- set stage
       id: req.body.id,     // <-- id not _id
       sku: req.body.sku,
       total_qty: req.body.total_qty,
       current_qty: req.body.current_qty
      } 
    }   
  ).then(result => {
    res.status(200).json({ message: "Update successful!" });
  });
});
```

There is no need to create new `Inventory` etc since all you need is to update an existing one based on `sku`

Here is more documentation on [updateOne](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.updateOne/index.html)