# Reg: data in mongo reflecting with other dates also:

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

Am using below mongo db query, while getting output am seeing the output with 08th Jan also, is there any changes needs to implement in query, thanks.

below is the query with timestamp selecting from 07th Jan 00 to 07th Jan 23:59:00, selecting the function status: FO_AE", "nonFO_AE", "FO_AF", "nonFO_AF", "FO_voip", "nonFO_voip", "FO_DS1", "nonFO_DS1"

```
db.actions.aggregate([{ 
        $match: { 
            "$and": [{ 
                "timeStamp": { 
                    "$gte": ISODate("2021-01-07T00:00:00.000-0400"), 
                    "$lt": ISODate("2021-01-07T23:59:00.000-0400") 
                } 
            }, { 
                "functionStatus": { 
                    "$in": ["FO_AE", "nonFO_AE", "FO_AF", "nonFO_AF", "FO_voip", "nonFO_voip", "FO_DS1", "nonFO_DS1"] 
                } 
            }] 
        } 
    }, 
    { 
        $group: { 
            _id: { 
                Dates: { 
                    $dateToString: { 
                        format: "%Y-%m-%d", 
                        date: "$timeStamp" 
                    } 
                }, 
                FS: "$functionStatus" 
            }, 
            JOBCOUNT: { 
                $addToSet: "$jobId" 
            } 
        } 
    }, 
    { 
        $project: { 
            "_id": NumberInt(0), 
            "Dates": "$_id.Dates", 
            "FS": "$_id.FS", 
            "Total_JOB_FO_USE_DV": { 
                $size: "$JOBCOUNT" 
            } 
        } 
    } 
 ])
 
 
 
 /* 1 */
{
    "Dates" : "2021-01-08",
    "FS" : "nonFO_AE",
    "Total_JOB_FO_USE_DV"" : 2
}

/* 2 */
{
    "Dates" : "2021-01-07",
    "FS" : "nonFO_DS1",
    "Total_JOB_FO_USE_DV" : 7
}

/* 3 */
{
    "Dates" : "2021-01-07",
    "FS" : "nonFO_AF",
    "Total_JOB_FO_USE_DV"" : 24
}

/* 4 */
{
    "Dates" : "2021-01-07",
    "FS" : "nonFO_AE",
    "Total_JOB_FO_USE_DV"" : 20
}
```

Thanks expert please find one sample document from collection:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : 947771683,
    "eventId" : "ALSWA-02-13-007",
    "eventName" : "",
    "timeStamp" : ISODate("2020-10-10T05:47:08.421Z"),
    "eventMethod" : "AI response",
    "resourceName" : "",
    "targetType" : "",
    "resourseUrl" : "",
    "operationName" : "getLastReleaseNumber",
    "functionStatus" : "FO_AE",
    "results" : "{\"flowStatus\":\"SUCCESS\",\"flowStatusMessage\":\"\",\"lastRlsNum\":\"0.1\",\"alasUpgTy\":\"F\"}",
    "pageId" : "",
    "ban" : "",
    "jobId" : "",
    "wrid" : "",
    "jobType" : "",
    "Uid" : "mbq",
    "techRegion" : "",
    "recordPublishIndicator" : "Y",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have any unique field / combination of fields, use that as `_id`. Refer about [_id](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9694460/difference-between-id-and-id-fields-in-mongodb)

Otherwise, you just use `insertone, insertMany` methods without, `_id` in it. It ll be automatically generated by driver.

Comment: HI experts, any suggestion how to acheive above result.

Comment: Give us some documents and we can check that